# Format response from mongoose into a model

Tags: mongodb, express

How do you go about formatting the data response from mongoose? For a simple Post Schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
},{
  timestamps: true
});
```

Whenever I do a GET request to find all the post, It returns me all its fields including `_id` and `__v` in which I wouldn't want to return those fields in an API.

Is there a way I would select only certain fields that I would want to return?

As far as I've found was that I could set a second parameter of `title` onto my query and it would return only the `_id` and `title`.

```
const post  = await Post.find({},'title');
```

I find the method above isn't the proper way to filter fields in cases in the future where the values are deeply nested object and we would like to pick out certain values.

Is there perhaps a way to create a Model/Class and pick the fields based on the Model/Class and return the respond?

Comment: or you could exclude things you don't want with `find().select('-__v')`. Which then return everything else other than `__v` or whatever key you put in there. Eg: `find().select('-_id -__v')`, if you wanna exclude `_id` and `__v`

Comment: And this also works with `find().populate('ex', '-_id -__v')`. First parameters being the `key` that you `ref` to other schema, while the second parameter would be the `key` that you want or want to exclude

Comment: it depends on your use case though. If you want to have something that really dynamic and changes all the time *(the queries)*, then incorporation of GraphQL will make this work wonderfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` from `mongoose`.

You can either select only the fields you want.

```js
var find = await model.find({}).select("my_field")
```

Or not show the fields you don't want

```js
var find = await model.find({}).select("-my_field")
```

Check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: This seems to be the answer for a simple Model but perhaps If the model is more complex I could incorporate GraphQl as mentioned by @lala